# Overlaying station locations as points on tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I have managed to plot a map of London using tmap in R:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
library(OpenStreetMap)

qtm("London")        
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(lnd) + 
  tm_polygons(alpha = 0.7, legend.show = FALSE) +   
  tm_basemap(server = c('OpenStreetMap'))
```

But now I want to overlay some different sized bubbles on top of this map to show the number of tweets that mention a particular train station. Here is an **example** of what I want the bubbles to look like:

[image]

My train station data is like this with the lat/long for each of the stations and the volume of tweets: https://filebin.net/emjnete8pf0ulxpe

When I load the stations data, I know I am meant to convert to an sf object (see below):

```
stations  <- read.csv("Stations_example.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
stations1 <- st_as_sf(stations, coords = c('Long', 'Lat'), crs=4326)
```

After this I get stuck - I am not sure how to get this information on the map in the way I want it.

Can anyone help? I am not wedded to using `tmap`. If there is a solution using another R package, I am happy to give that a go (although, I cannot use `ggmap` due to having to sign up with a credit card).

---

**UPDATE 18/12/2019**:

Thanks to Spacedman for his suggestion. It didn't initially work when I kept the `tm_polygons` bit in. This seemed to do the trick:

```
qtm("London")       
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(stations1)+
  tm_bubbles(col = "red", size= "Volume", scale = .5) +
  tm_basemap(server = c('OpenStreetMap'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another layer on top of your existing `tmap` object using `tm_shape` and a function for how you want to draw that layer.

```
tm_shape(lnd) + 
  tm_polygons(alpha = 0.7, legend.show = FALSE) +   
  tm_shape(tweets) + 
  tm_bubbles(size="count") + 
  tm_basemap(server = c('OpenStreetMap'))
```

where `tweets` is your spatial object and `counts` is a column with the number of tweets at each point location.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was the ```tm_polygons``` bit that wasn't working for me. I posted what I ended up using in the original question.